# Rendering a Router Component in Angular 4 View

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Is there a way to render a router component without explicitly having to execute the `router.navigate` method?

I currently have a method that looks like this:

```
public onClickEdit(id: number): void {
    this.router.navigate(['...', '...', '...', id], {queryParams: {
        id: id
    }});
}
```

If I instead, want to render this component directly inside of my view, could I do so?

```
<div class="my-component">
    <!-- Can I render my component directly in here? -->
    router.navigate(...)
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just have to give it a `selector`:
For example if you want to render DemoComponent in your component:

**DemoComponent:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'demo-component',
  templateUrl: './demo-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo-component.scss']
})
export class DemoComponent {

}
```

**Your component:**

```
<div class="my-component">
    <!-- render demo component -->
    <demo-component></demo-component>

</div>
```

Don't forget to import DemoComponent into your component.